# returning random values from variables of dynamic array with struct

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-arrays

I am having the following problem..: 
I run my code and it reads in any number of authors correctly but when I go on to print the author's full name and date to the screen I get (for example) this:

[Example console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMYZh.jpg)

As you can see the string/char values for the names are correct but the integer values for the date are just random numbers..

```
typedef struct{
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
}Date;

typedef struct{
    char lastName[30];
    char firstName[30];
    Date birthday;
}Person;

int main(){

    //assigning memory dynamically to array of authors
    int n;
    printf("How many authors should be added to the archive?\n");
    scanf("%i", &n);

    //array of authors
    Person* authors = (Person*) calloc(n, sizeof(Person));

    //reading authors
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        addAuthor(authors, i);
    }

    //writing authors to screen
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printAuthor(authors[i]);
    }

    free(authors);
    return 0;
}

Date inputDate(){
    Date d;
    printf("Input year: ");
    scanf(" %s", &d.year);
    printf("Input month: ");
    scanf(" %s", &d.month);
    printf("Input day: ");
    scanf(" %s", &d.day);
    return d;
}

Person inputAuthor(){
    Person p;
    printf("\nInput last name: ");
    scanf(" %s", &p.lastName);
    printf("Input last name: ");
    scanf(" %s", &p.firstName);
    p.birthday = inputDate();
    return p;
}

void printAuthor(Person p){
    printf("\n%s, %s born %i.%i.%i", p.lastName, p.firstName, p.birthday.day, p.birthday.month, p.birthday.year);
}

void addAuthor(Person* p, unsigned u){
    p[u] = inputAuthor();
}
```

Comment: `%s` is for reading strings, not integers.

Comment: 2nd `printf("Input last name: ");` --> `printf("Input first name: ");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading in the date incorrectly:

```
printf("Input year: ");
scanf(" %s", &d.year);
printf("Input month: ");
scanf(" %s", &d.month);
printf("Input day: ");
scanf(" %s", &d.day);
```

These fields are of type `int`, but the `%s` format specifier expect a pointer to a `char` array.  Using the incorrect format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To read integer values, use the `%d` format specifier.

```
printf("Input year: ");
scanf("%d", &d.year);
printf("Input month: ");
scanf("%d", &d.month);
printf("Input day: ");
scanf("%d", &d.day);
```